# Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. How can I solve the problem?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to delete an element by id, but the TS compiler swears that the undefined type can come. I don't know what to do anymore. I'm just learning :(

*Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.*

**ProjectsPage**

```
const removeProject = (id: string) => {
    projectServer.deleteProject(id);
    return (
        <div className="projectPage">
            {projects.map(projects =>
                <ProjectItem project={projects} key={projects.id} removeProject={removeProject} />
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
```

**projectItem**

```
interface IProjectProps {
    project: Project,
    removeProject: (id: string) => void 
}

export const ProjectItem: FC<IProjectProps> = ({project, removeProject}) => {
    return (
        <div className="projectItem">
            <div className="name">{project.id}</div>
            <div className="name">{project.name}</div>
            <div className="description">{project.description}</div>
            <div className="actionBar">
                <Button onClick={() = removeProject(project.id)} text="Delete"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**class Project**

```
export class Project {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    constructor() {
        this.id = '';
        this.name = '';
        this.description = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: you could write string | undefined instead of just string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export class Project {
id?: string;
name?: string;
description?: string;
...
```

Documentation link - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties